# Ordered Parallel code runs slower than single threading. Is there a solution?

Tags: c, openmp, parallel-processing

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(x) private (y, z, f) ordered
for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    #pragma omp ordered
    for (y = 0; y < 512; y++) {
        for (z = 0, f = 0; z < 512; z++) {
            x[f++] = z + i + y;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code runs slower than non SMP execution by about 20%
 on a dual core. Without the "#pragma omp ordered" it is about 50% faster than non SMP.

The x[f++] sequence is assumed it has to remain in an ordered form since it's similarly reused later.

Can ordered code be faster than single threading? Is there another method to achieve it?

System is win32/mingw-w64.

Comment: This code makes no sense - you overwrite x without taking account of prior values.  Only the innermost loop actually writes.  just set i and z to 512 and run the inner loop, your code will run 250,000 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really ordered, since the results of one iteration do not depend upon the previous, except for your use of `f`.

Can you derive `f` from `i`,`y` and `z`?  It looks like you can.  For example:

```
f = z + y * 512 + i * 512 * 512 + initial_f;
```

Now your code is unordered, and you can get real benefits from parallelization.

Comment: I don't get how you come to that solution, `f` is always set to `0` at the start of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Single-threaded/-core code is often faster than multi-threaded/-core due to saturation of the memory system. What happens is that the memory work required by the single thread is close to or at the limit of what the memory system can deliver. Add another thread/core that requires the same work and both threads/cores will need to share what the memory system can provide resulting in wait states and slower execution

After profiling and optimization of the memory work you may reach the point where the multi-threaded code is faster. The optimization requires moving data into non-shared memory (i e L1 & L2 caches) and minimizing accesses to shared memory (L3 & RAM).

The optimization solution is more or less unique to the application at hand. It is not trivial (though some third-party SW vendors will try to say that with their product it's a piece of cake). Once you've done it you'll at least have learned what constructs should be avoided and what techniques are useful.

Answer (score -1):

You are obviously relying on a shared vector `x` in the inner loop. So each access to that variable must be mutexed by OMP. No wonder that the "parallel" version is slower than the sequential one.

It is difficult to advise you what to change, since your code makes no sense to me at all. What do you expect the result to be? If you have `ordered` the final result in `x` will be the version for the value `i` set to `511`. If you don't, it is whoever thread wins for each individual entry.

And what the h... is your `f` supposed to do? When evaluated it has the same value as `w`, no? This is just adding noise to make it harder to understand.